Literature Survey for Version Management
As part of an industry project, I was looking for a literature survey on the User Experience of products where versions are provided for the main entity. For example:

Google Docs automates/hides the creation of versions (unlike Git, which has an explicit check-in/check-out model).
Confluence allows one to create drafts for a document,but doesn't support a branching model like Git.
Bazaar simplifies version management challenges but removing certain features.

Versioning UX is common across all these use cases, regardless of persona (Google Docs/Sheets are used by non-technical personas like sales/marketing and school teachers) while Git is more advanced. Also, based on each of these personas, certain "limitations" are acceptable (like merging and picking differences from various versions, which is facilitated in Git but not in Google Docs).
Finally, some personas (like photographers who manage multiple edits of a photo in Photoshop) have their own "homebrewed" version management process (e.g. adding versions to file names).
Is there any research work which surveys how people work with versioned entities?

I came across this paper: https://dl.acm.org/doi/pdf/10.1145/3555756 but it's pretty recent.
